# Loading child theme files in a child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I have a function that essentially sais go to the theme  folder and go look for this directory and this path, it uses:

```
get_template_directory()
```

but it seems that it is looking for said file in the parent theme, is there an equivelent for the child theme, to say - go look ONLY in your own directory for this, instead of the parent theme directory

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_directory();` is literally looking for the parent theme. (Parent's are a 'template', child theme's are... well... 'child themes')

use `<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` instead, or

```
<?php 
$theme = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
echo = $theme;
?>
```

or in your functions.php file you can do something like

```
define( 'CHILD_DIR', get_stylesheet_directory() );
```

then for images or something you can do

```
printf(CHILD_DIR.'/images/image.jpg');
```

**EDIT**

[Here's the source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) for some of that, and notice the 3rd or 4th paragraph

> In the event a child theme is being used, this function will return the child's theme directory URI. Use get_template_directory_uri() instead if you want the parent directory.